# Finding the point of intersection of two lines that lie in the projective space P3

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space

I have this question and I'm not entirely sure how to go about it. I understand how to go about the problem in the projective space $\mathbb{P}2$: if I have two lines $l1$ and $l2$, then their intersection will be at a point $x$ such that:
$$
l_1 = (a_1, b_1, c_!)^T \\
l_2 = (a_2, b_2, c_2)^T \\
l_1 \times l_2 = x
$$

However, I am unsure how to translate this problem to the projective space $\mathbb{P}3$.

Adding onto this, how would I go about finding the line joining two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $\mathbb{P}3$? Would it be the same as finding the point of intersection as above?

Any help, links to resources exploring the problem would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> If it matters, two generic lines do not intersect in projective 3-space (because two generic planes in 4-space intersect only at $0$). It might help to edit the question to specify how you define points and lines in projective space; depending on definitions, a point of projective space "is" a line through $0$ in affine space "one dimension higher," a projective line "is" similarly an affine plane, and "finding the line through two points" amounts to finding the plane containing two lines through $0$.